# CSS3 centering and CCS3 animation

Tags: css

I use the following code on many divs in my site to do vertical and horizontal centering in responsive divs.

```
            -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
            -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
            -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
```

However then I want to animate my buttons through css3 transforms, it jumps around as it seems the animation bypasses my centerings with this "hack". Does anyone know of a similar hack to actually make just css animations doable or is this a thing I loose when I want to center things with css?

Comment: please show the CSS you are using to rotate those divs +HTML code. And even better, reproduce your issue in jsfiddle or other.

Comment: Did u mean css3 animation

Comment: @Shadow: no necessarily. The transform property can be used for animation too like scaling, rotating and such.

Comment: @web-tiki: You can see it here. Try to deactivate the animation-classes for the green button and see if go back to the center: http://www.cphrecmedia.dk/musikdk/stage/hashtag-comp.php